# How can we display only images in a option tag of a select in HTML?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display images/icons in the options of a select tag. So could anyone please suggest a way out.

I tried using class names (which provides the image url), i.e

```
<option data-bind ="text:Caption, attr {'class': className}"></option>
```

But, it doesn't work without "text:Caption". So, can anyone please suggest a way out.

Comment: I tried implementing it this way- <option data-bind ="text:Caption, attr :{'class':className}"></option>

Comment: .className{
background-image: url('base64encodedUrl');
}

Comment: With HTML and CSS you can't, I don't think bootstrap supports this either. This is often achieved by some java-script that replaces the `select`  with additional HTML and CSS (`divs`, `lists` etc) that update the now hidden select when interacted with. Are you using another library like **knockout**?

Comment: @JonP- Thanks for your response. Currently I am using bootstrap-select. We have something called as selectpicker and using that I have implemented. Yes we do have knockout and typescript.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox you can just add a background image to option:

```
<select>
  <option style="background-image:url(male.png);">male</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(female.png);">female</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(others.png);">others</option>
</select>
```

Better yet, you can separate HTML and CSS like that

**HTML**

```
<select id="gender">
  <option>male</option>
  <option>female</option>
  <option>others</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select#gender option[value="male"]   { background-image:url(male.png);   }
select#gender option[value="female"] { background-image:url(female.png); }
select#gender option[value="others"] { background-image:url(others.png); }
```

In **other browsers** the only way of doing that would be using some JS widget library, like for example [**jQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/), e.g. using **[Selectable](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/)**.

From jQuery UI 1.11, **[Selectmenu](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render)** widget is available, which is very close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will have a look at selectable but as of now I tried using bootstrap-select, but it doesn't work without the text and what I want is only image icons being displayed in dropdown.  The firefox option would not work for me as I need something which is compatible across browsers.